# Can we pass a column instead of a variable to access nth item of a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, pointers

My data contains multiple columns, on which I have done a group by and given row numbers based on the group by. I'm using python here
The column 'Text' is a list of strings. The entire 'Text' was initially 1 string, which is split into a list with ; as the delimiter. Rownumber are integers.
What I want to do here is, consider Rownum as a pointer towards output column.
If Rownum= 0, then my output should be Text[0], i.e a.

If Rownum = 2, Output should be 2nd item of the list Text, Text[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bLFo.png), i.e b

To achieve this, I tried:

`df['Outpu'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['Text'].split(';'),axis = 1)[df['Row_num']]`

But I got the error "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis".
Not entirely sure what it means.
I have attached an image of my data and output, but also have written down the format incase image isn't available. Hope I explained the situation clear enough.
Original Text is not a,b,c: Just put it there for easier understanding. This is the text:

```
Text: [TAF KPHX 010246Z 0103/0206 VRB04KT P6SM FEW070 BKN160 ;FM010700 10005KT P6SM SCT060 BKN150 ;FM012100 21006KT P6SM SCT070 SCT140 ;FM020000 26005KT P6SM FEW070 SCT140]

Row num     Text          Output

0         [a,b,c,d]        a
1         [a,b,c,d]        b
2         [a,b,c,d]        c
3         [a,b,c,d]        d
0         [d,e,f]          d
1         [d,e,f]          e
2         [d,e,f]          f
```

Comment: Please don't link to images, edit the question and add the data as text.

Answer (score 0):

As i see, Delimeter should be "," not ";". Since "Text" is a single string then first remove square brackets uisng `replace()` then split it by ',' and then extract the element using index in "Row_num"

```
df =pd.DataFrame({"Row_num": [0,1,2,3,0,1,2],"Text":['[a,b,c,d]', '[a,b,c,d]', '[a,b,c,d]', '[a,b,c,d]', '[d,e,f]', '[d,e,f]', '[d,e,f]']})
df["Output"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Text.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",")[x.Row_num], axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
    Row_num Text    Output
0   0   [a,b,c,d]   a
1   1   [a,b,c,d]   b
2   2   [a,b,c,d]   c
3   3   [a,b,c,d]   d
4   0   [d,e,f]     d
5   1   [d,e,f]     e
6   2   [d,e,f]     f
```

Lets say you have "," as a delimeter in Text column then try:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({"Row_num": [0,1,2,3,4],"Text":["a;b;c;d;e"]*5})
df["Output"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Text.split(";")[x.Row_num], axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
 Row_num    Text    Output
0   0   a;b;c;d;e   a
1   1   a;b;c;d;e   b
2   2   a;b;c;d;e   c
3   3   a;b;c;d;e   d
4   4   a;b;c;d;e   e
```

**Make sure** data is available in Text at mentioned Row_num

Comment: This is the original format of the text. I used alphabets just to make it easier to understand. TAF KPHX 010246Z 0103/0206 VRB04KT P6SM FEW070 BKN160 ;FM010700 10005KT P6SM SCT060 BKN150 ;FM012100 21006KT P6SM SCT070 SCT140 ;FM020000 26005KT P6SM FEW070 SCT140

Comment: The example you provided has "," in Text

Comment: I understand, it was a mistake from my end. Should have used ; as delimiter. Can you help me out with the actual text part? I tried your solution for my data by tweaking it a bit, but got an error 'list index out of range'

Comment: It should give error because delimeter was "," so everytime the split return only one value.
Well, Edited the answer for you. Please check it out.